# Python Selenium How to handle NoSuchElementException from while loop/if else statement

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, while-loop, nosuchelementexception

I'm trying to write a while loop where if an element isn't found it does certain tasks, however when the element is not found, it throws an error `NoSuchElementException` as if there is no element, instead of going to the 'else' statement.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('add-to-bag')

while True:
    if elem.is_displayed():
        False
    else:
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        driver.refresh()
        sleep(randint(5, 10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your code block when you mention `if an element is found it does certain tasks, however when the element is not found, it throws an error code` is **perfect**.

### Explanation

The code to find the element is just before the `while/if` block started. So when your `find_element_by_id('add-to-bag')` **fails** instead of returning an element it is returning **NoSuchElementException** which you havn't handled.

### Solution

A simple solution would be to induce a **`try-except`** block for **`find_element_by_id('add-to-bag')`** as follows :

```
try :
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id('add-to-bag')
    if elem.is_displayed():
        //implement your logic

except NoSuchElementException :
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    driver.refresh()
    sleep(randint(5, 10))
```